# Strange white space on the right (when zoomed in or on mobile devices)

Tags: html, css, web

i am building my website for few months now and recently faced an issue, i can't get rid of.

I don't understand why i see a white border (seems like a misplaced width or padding value) on the right of my website, after zooming in / or using a mobile device with width less than '975px', as this is the  main width value of my website.
I want the main container of the content, header and footer to stay right in the center of the page even after zooming in. Did i miss something? How do i need to rewrite my css? I would appreciate if someone could help me somehow!

- website: http://www.ansgarscheffold.com
- css: http://www.ansgarscheffold.com/wp_dir/wp-content/themes/wp-framework/library/media/layouts/2col-r.css

regards & thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see it in my browser, which one are you using?

Comment: safari, firefox & iPhone 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your header class width, make it width:100% and everything is fine

```
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 250px;
background: url(http://www.ansgarscheffold.com/img/ansgar_scheffold_drawing.jpg) no-repeat;
position: relative;
background-position-x: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think This line is causing a problem:

```
<ul class="nav-list" style="float: none; width: 25em;">
```

`width:25em;` is overflowing.

Comment: Your `.nav` has `width:400px` and its child `ul.nav-list` has `width:450px!important` its overflowing. i.e. when you `zoom+` your `nav-menu` goes out of the `wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are causing your issue as far as I can see. You need to add `max-width: 100%` to `.container` also remove `float: right;` and `width: 400px` from `.nav` as this is causing overflow.